# Match all characters except for those that start with specific characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to match all characters except for character array that starts with `_ah`:

```
_ah\foo
_ah\foo\bar
```

This is my current regex: `\b(?!\_ah(\w+))\w+\b`

However this regex still matches the one listed above. What could be the problem in my regex?

Comment: Where are the backslashes ?

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve. Could you give few examples? Input and expected output would be nice.

Comment: Maybe you already did this, but in Java `_` doesn't need to be escaped, and `\b` and `\w` do, so your regex would look like this: `"\\b(?!_ah(\\w+))\\w+\\b"`. Also you should probably include the backslashes from your arrays (also escaped), I'm not sure how they can match your regex without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to match words that don't start with `_ah`..

```
\b(?!_ah)\w+\b
```

This would match `foo`,`bar`